# c# DES PaddingMode.None

Tags: c#, encryption, padding, des

I have the next code in c# to encrypt a decrypt

```
Crypto.BlockSize = 64;
Crypto.FeedbackSize = 8;
Crypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
Crypto.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
Encryptor = Crypto.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678"));
Decryptor = Crypto.CreateDecryptor(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("12345678"));
```

I have coded another encrypter/decrypter in other language.

DES uses 8 bytes padding. When the text to encrypt is 8 bytes or mult of 8, both works exactly.

The problem is when the size is 12. C# uses 12 bytes since it doesnt need any kind of padding... but in the other library i'm forced to use mult of 8 as input so i have checked to complete with all 0x00 and 0xFF but then i get different results in the last bytes.

What is c# doing when no padding and no mult of 8?... from where is it getting the rest of the missing bytes?

Comment: I have been the last 12 hours searching for a solution with no luck.. I just asked here and I had a intuition flash in my mind... and now it is confirmed.. Directly it doesnt encrypts de last bytes....

Comment: _but in the other library i'm forced to use mult of 8 as input_ It's the same in C#. Under the mentioned conditions (DES-ECB, `PaddingMode.None`, plaintext length is not an integer multiple of the block length) a `CryptographicException` is thrown. At least in my tests (with `TransformFinalBlock` as well as `CryptoStream`).